# Basic progress bar for each line of output in an async bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say I have this basic bash script for installing Vim plugins:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

plugins=(
tpope/vim-endwise
tpope/vim-fugitive
tpope/vim-surround
tpope/vim-unimpaired
)

rm -rf $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/*
mkdir $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/start

installplugin() {
  plugin=”$(echo “$1" | sed -e ‘s/.*[\/]//’)”
  git clone –depth=1 -q https://github.com/$1.git \
    $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/start/$plugin
  rm -rf $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/start/$plugin/.git*
  echo $plugin installed!
}

for repo in ${plugins[@]}; do
  installplugin “$repo” &
done

wait
```

It clones each repository in the array `plugins` to `~/.vim/pack/bundle/start`, and does so asynchronously.

Ignoring the async element  of the script (the `&` at the end of `installplugin “$repo” &`) for the moment, how would I add a `.` to the end of a line such as `Installing $plugin` (which would show at the *start* of the installation process of a given plugin) every second or so, as a form of progress bar, perhaps outputting `Done.` on the same line after completion of that plugin, then moving on to the next plugin?

Here is my stab at the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

plugins=(
tpope/vim-endwise
tpope/vim-fugitive
tpope/vim-surround
tpope/vim-unimpaired
)

rm -rf $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/*
mkdir $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/start

progressbar() {
  until [ $installed -eq 1 ]; do
    sleep 0.1
    echo -n '.'
  done
}

installplugin() {
  installed=0
  echo -n "Installing $plugin"
  progressbar &
  plugin=”$(echo “$1" | sed -e ‘s/.*[\/]//’)”
  git clone –depth=1 -q https://github.com/$1.git \
    $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/start/$plugin
  rm -rf $HOME/.vim/pack/bundle/start/$plugin/.git*
  installed=1
  echo ' Done.'
}

for repo in ${plugins[@]}; do
  installplugin “$repo”
done

wait
```

It does not work, but I do not understand why.

What I assume is a simple thing to solve becomes much more complicated if you remember that the original script was asynchronous, as you would have to remember how many lines up the output of each `Installing` message is from the bottom, and then update the lines with dots until their respective plugin has been installed. I need to modify the original script to show the basic form of progress bar I described earlier?

Comment: Hi Aramis. This could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script

Comment: For anyone coming across this, the script wrongly uses “smart quotes” instead of "straight quotes". This will cause the script to fail to run accurately (if at all)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work since the shell variable `installed` is two different variables in the `progressbar` function (in its subshell environment) and in the `installplugin` function.  The `progressbar` function is executed in a subshell since you start it as a background task.  It will inherit the value from its parent environment when the function is started, but the parent will not be able to set a new value in the child environment (the `progressbar` subshell).

This still uses `progressbar` as a background task, but lets it set up a trap to exit the infinite loop.  The main function, `foo`, triggers the trap by sending it the appropriate signal when it's done.

```
progressbar () {
    trap 'break' USR1

    while printf '.' >&2; do
        sleep 0.25
    done
}

foo () {
    progressbar & pid="$!"

    echo 'working...'
    sleep 5
    echo 'done.'

    kill -s USR1 "$pid"
}

foo
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This works perfectly ignoring the async part of the script. How would I adapt it so it works when running `foo &` multiple times? If it helps, it is known how many times `foo` will be run.

Comment: @AramisRazzaghipour How would you envisage multiple progress bars being displayed?

Comment: Basically `working...` is echoed multiple times, each on its own line, and then the dots from `progressbar` appear on each line independently. I’m guessing that the `\e[xA` escape sequence will be used to overwrite specific lines?

Comment: @AramisRazzaghipour You would probably need some sort of `curses` library to do that. Any implementation that just prints dots in a background subshell can not be aware of how many other progress bars are currently running concurrently. I might get back to this late though.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the recommended [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428661/multiple-progress-bar) to do something like this involves temporary files …